# Play sound on key press - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is wrong with my code the sound is not playing when I am pressing the keys.

```
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;i++)
{

    document.querySelectorAll("button")[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
     
        var buttoninnerhtml = this.innerHTML;

        makesound(buttoninnerhtml);
       
    
        
    });


}

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){

  makesound(event,key);

});

function makesound(key)
{
  
    switch (key) {
        case "w":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;

        case "a":
                var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
                audio.play();
                break;

        case "s":
                 var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
                audio.play();
                break;
    
        case "d":
                var audio = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
                audio.play();
                break;

         case "j":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
            audio.play();
            break;
            
        case "k":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
                    audio.play();
                    break;

        case "l":
            var audio = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
             audio.play();
                    break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+play+sound+press+key+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Have only one event listener and pass expected values. or better:  use delegation - no need for switch even. Just use the event.code

Comment: How you call the function `makesound(event, key)`, does not match the function signature, `function makesound(key)`. `key` inside your function will actually contain the Event object now.

Answer (score 1):

Your

makesound(event,key);

is passing the event and the makesound expects a key as first parameter

I suggest you delegate and use a lookup table

```js
const sounds = {
  'KeyW': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/tom1.ogg',
  'KeyA': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/tom2.ogg',
  'KeyS': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/tom3.ogg',
  'KeyD': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/pad1.ogg',
  'KeyJ': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/snare1.ogg',
  'KeyK': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/crash1.ogg',
  'KeyL': 'https://www.virtualdrumming.com/drums/virtual-drum-sounds/hip-hop/kik.ogg'
}

const play = sound => {
  console.log("playing",sound)
  var audio = new Audio(sound);
  audio.play();
}


document.getElementById('drumSet').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button');
  if (tgt) play(sounds[tgt.id])
})

window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) { console.log(e.code)
  if (sounds[e.code]) {
    console.log("clicking",e.code)
    document.getElementById(e.code).click()
  }  
})
```

```html
<div id="drumSet">
  <button id="KeyW">Tom 1</button>
  <button id="KeyA">Tom 2</button>
  <button id="KeyS">Tom 3</button>
  <button id="KeyD">Tom 4</button>
  <button id="KeyJ">Snare</button>
  <button id="KeyK">Crash</button>
  <button id="KeyL">Kick-bass</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `makesound(event.key);`. This will call your key parameter function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).